# Set flag based on 3 checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, refactoring

I have three checkboxes:

```
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb1;
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb2;
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cb3;
```

All of these checkboxes have the same CheckedChanged event:

```
this.cb1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_CheckedChanged);
this.cb2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_CheckedChanged);
this.cb3.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_CheckedChanged);
```

I have a flag which I need to check later in my app based on checked checkboxes.
So, the possibilities are:

1. Only cb_1
2. Only cb_2
3. Only cb_3
4. Only cb_1&cb_2
5. Only cb_1&cb_3
6. Only cb_2&cb_3
7. All

So I created an enum:

```
    public enum LimitCbs
    {
        cb_1,
        cb_2,
        cb_3,
        cb_1_2,
        cb_1_3,
        cb_2_3,
        All,
    }
```

For now, my logic looks like:

```
private void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cb1.Checked && !cb2.Checked && !cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_1;
    }

    else if (!cb1.Checked && cb2.Checked && !cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_2;
    }

    else if (!cb1.Checked && !cb2.Checked && cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_3;
    }

    else if (cb1.Checked && cb2.Checked && !cbxExportOnlyManholes.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_1_2;
    }

    else if (cb1.Checked && !cb2.Checked && cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_1_3;
    }

    else if (!cb1.Checked && cb2.Checked && cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.cb_2_3;
    }

    else if (cb1.Checked && cb2.Checked && cb3.Checked)
    {
        cfg = LimitCbs.All;
    }
}
```

Is there any more fancy way to check all requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I would represent checkbox states as 3-digits binary number. So if cb1 is checked then my number is `001`, if cb2 then `010`, if cb1 and cb3 then `101`, if all then `111` etc. So every possible combination now has corresponding binary number.
Then let's change your enum as follows:

```
public enum LimitCbs
{
    None = 0, //000
    cb_1 = 1, //001
    cb_2 = 2, //010
    cb_3 = 4, //100
    cb_1_2 = 3, //011
    cb_1_3 = 5, //101
    cb_2_3 = 6, //110
    All = 7, //111
}
```

Finally, your event listener method will change to this:

```
private void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if checked then "1" else "0"
    String s1 = Convert.ToInt32(cb1.Checked).ToString(); 
    String s2 = Convert.ToInt32(cb2.Checked).ToString();
    String s3 = Convert.ToInt32(cb3.Checked).ToString();
    //concatenate all digits;
    String s = s3 + s2 + s1;
    //convert string in binary to int in decimal
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(s, 2);
    //and finally get enum from int
    cfg = (LimitCbs)i;
}
```

It is shorter than your method.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your enum with the `[Flags]` attribute, and then combine the states with a bitwise OR.

```
[Flags]
enum LimitCbs
{ None = 0, First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 4 }

...

var boxesChecked = LimitCbs.None;    

if (cb1.Checked)
    boxesChecked |= LimitCbs.First;
if (cb2.Checked)
    boxesChecked |= LimitCbs.Second;
```